# can't catch python EOFError

Tags: python

I read a file which only contains one line. However, I can't stop reading the file until the loop end. i.e. the python doesn't throw EOFError exception. what't wrong with my code?

```
for x in range(5):
  try:
    line = file.readlines()
  except EOFError:
    break
  print "Line:",line
```

The output is:

```
Line: ['nice\n']
Line: []
Line: []
Line: []
Line: []
```

Comment: Why do you have the loop? `x` is never used.

Comment: What are you **really** trying to do?

Comment: @Tichodroma   I'm wring a program like head, which can read a filename and number of lines you want to see. Even a file only contains one line, however, if I want't to see the first 10 lines of the file, the program will print 9 blank lines. I just want it print one line. this code is just a fragment of my program, simulating to see 5 lines

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`readlines()` reads the whole document and returns the list of lines, not just a single line.

You probably meant to use `file.readline()` - but even that does not raise an error, so you have to do something else, like checking `if not line.endswith("\n"): break` or `len(line) < 1` to detect the EOF.

Personally I would write the same functionality something like:

```
with open("filename") as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        print("Line: %s" % line)
        if i > 5 or not line:
            break
```

Or if you want to get rid of the extra newlines, change the print statement to:

```
print("Line: %s" % line.rstrip("\n"))
```

Comment: `file.readline()` doesn't guarantee that the line will end with `\n`.

Comment: Until now I just know readline won't throw an EOFError. Thank you so much.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: really? The help says `Retain newline.` - In any case, I added suggestion to check for `len(line)` before your comment.

Comment: It can only retain a newline that exists in the first place.

Comment: ok, so print before break is the correct way - fixed in a sec.

Comment: EOF checking might have made sense in the OP's code but it doesn't in the slightest in the sample above as the enumerated result of `f` will never let your loop beyond the number of lines in the file...  Also, the proper way to check whether `line = f.readline()` reached EOF is by checking whether `line` is empty: e.g. `if not line: break`.  a.l.a. documentation: *if f.readline() returns an empty string, the end of the file has been reached*

Comment: Since `readline()` does not remove newlines, it will only return an empty string at the end of the line. So it's enough to check `or not line` or `line == ''`

Answer (score 2):

`file.readlines()` *never* raises `EOFError`.

Answer (score 1):

from the docs it says that reading a file will return an empty string at EOF while input() and raw_input() will return an EOFError when EOF is reached without reading any data

http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.EOFError